# Redirect a page in node.js to codeigniter

Tags: php, node.js, http

How to redirect a page fromnode.js to codeigniter on localhost...

1. I have tried this `href="localhost"` but it concatenate its server address like 
   `192.168.1.45` so its url comes like: `192.168.1.45/localhost`. if it is possible to
   remove server address to being concatenate before `href`, how can i unset the server
   address.

2 .In the router can i redirect page to http urls,how can i perform it.

Comment: how did you try `href="localhost"` ? can you post some relevant code on what you have done?

Comment: i have done this now i have change the href ot ip+port...so it redirects thanx.

Comment: if what you have done works, please post it as an answer and mark it as the best answer